# Why DMD is not able to compile the following D code snippet?

Tags: d

I am learning D and use [run.dlang.io](https://run.dlang.io) for debugging. The following code below runs without issues on [run.dlang.io](https://run.dlang.io):

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm;
import std.range;
import std.typecons;

static bool even(Tuple!(ulong, double) a) {
    return (a[0] & 1) == 0;   
}

void main() {
    double[] arr = [31, 22, -3, 44, 51, 26, 47, 58, 19, 10];  
    auto res1 = arr.enumerate.filter!(even).map!(a => a[1]);
    writeln(res1);    
}
```

However, DMD32 v2.088 throws exception while compiling the exact same code `dmd temp.d` on Windows 10.

```
Error: function temp.even(Tuple!(ulong, double) a) is not callable using argument types (Tuple!(uint, "index", double, "value"))
```

While LDC compiler (1.18.0-beta1): (based on DMD v2.088.0 and LLVM 8.0.1) compiles the same file without issues.

**run.dlang.io** uses 2.087 dmd compiler and somehow it magically works, why doesn't it work on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows your application is by default built for 32 bit. On OSX and Linux (which is what run.dlang.io is running) it's building by default for 64 bit.

Because of that, the array indices are uint and ulong respectively. In your code you used `Tuple!(ulong, double)`, but on 32 bit it's called with uint indices.

Instead of using ulong/uint you should use `size_t` for indices, which maps to uint/ulong. This is defined in [object.d](https://github.com/dlang/druntime/blob/master/src/object.d#L19), which is included by default.

So if you change your function to

```d
static bool even(Tuple!(size_t, double) a) {
    return (a[0] & 1) == 0;   
}
```

it will run on both 32 bit and 64 bit.

On Windows you can also test your code with dub by running it with `--arch=x86_64` or with the dmd flag `-m64` where it should already work without change. I recommend testing your application both on 32 bit and 64 bit always to make sure you are using `size_t` where needed.